# Checking if data is in database before adding data SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create an SQL statement that CHECKS IF A TABLE IS EMPTY before INSERTING data

```
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM characters)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO characters (1,Sam,Jordan,7,4,4,"Strength","Sam's muscular build provides +2 Storage Capacity","Meaty Punch","+2 Damage To Next Attack")
```

Error Produced:

```
21:26:01    BEGIN  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM characters) BEGIN  INSERT INTO characters (1,Sam,Jordan,7,4,4,"Strength","Sam's muscular build provides +2 Storage Capacity","Meaty Punch","+2 Damage To Next Attack")  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM characters) BEGIN  INSERT INTO characters (1,Sam,Jo' at line 2    0.000 sec
```

Comment: check syntax for `BEGIN`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Shreyas im not even sure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM characters)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO characters 
    VALUES
    (
       1,
       'Sam',
       'Jordan',
       7,
       4,
       4,
       'Strength',
       'Sam''s muscular build  provides +2 Storage Capacity',
       'Meaty Punch',
       '+2 Damage To Next Attack'
    )

END
```